# Applying attributes to the Partial classes

Tags: c#, .net

Following is my Partial class:

```
// File - DesignController.cs

[Authorize]
public partial class DesignerController : ApiController
{
   // Some Code
}

[Authorize]
public partial class DesignerController
{
   // Some Code
}
```

I need to understand the usage of the [Authorize] or similar attribute on the class, would it be fine to have it just on one of the partial class definition or all of them would have it. Current code is compiling but I need to understand the runtime issues of the above implementation

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On partial classes the attributes are merged at compilation time, so yes, you can have it on only one class.

Example:

```
[Obsolete]
public partial class Foo {}

[Authorize]
public partial class Foo {}
```

Compiles to:

```
[Obsolete]
[Authorize]
public partial class Foo {}
```

For further information on this you can look at [MSDN: Partial classes and methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/wa80x488.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can apply same attribute more than one time to a class,that's why it compiles.So your code is equivelant to

```
[Authorize]
[Authorize]
public class DesignerController
{
   // Some Code
}
```

If this is not intended you should remove the attribute from one of the declarations.

Comment: This is only true if the attribute allows multiple definitions on a member (i.e. `AllowMultiple = true`).